# Why is the default norm in R norm function the 1-norm?

Tags: r, matlab, norm

Is there a reason for that the default norm used for the `norm` function in R is the 1-norm?

I was translating some code from `matlab` to `R` and I ran into this, because the default there is the 2-norm.

It just seems intuitive to me that the default should be the 2-norm, that translates to Euclidian distance.

I hope someone can clarify this, or give any historical reason for this choice. The reason I am asking this question is to understand implementation choices of the norm functions in `matlab` and `R`. The following is an implementation of norm in R

```
function (x, type = c("O", "I", "F", "M", "2")) 
{
    if (identical("2", type)) {
        svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L)$d[1L]
    }
    else .Internal(La_dlange(x, type))
}
```

The default choice is `"O"`. In matlab and [python numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) the default is the 2-norm. It just seems weird to me that `R` is not consistent with that.

My gut feeling is that the implementation of the default option should correspond with the most used norm.

Comment: You should always consult the documentation when using a function unfamiliar to you, sometimes even if you believe to know the function.

Comment: I am aware of that @Roland, and that is what I do. I am just curious why this choice was made for the implementation of the norm function in R.

Comment: because it goes like 1,2 and inf probably?

Comment: @percusse that is likely the case, but there might be other reasons behind it.

Comment: If you have access to the LAPACK User's Guide, you could have a look at the LAPACK defaults.

Comment: @Roland I'll check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If R is related with LAPACK tightly, then the reason is simple. LAPACK is written in Fortran, which stores matrices column-wise, the 1-norm computing algorithm is column-oriented, so LAPACK tends to prefer 1-norm rather than other norms when there is a choice.

In other words, to compute the norm fast, R delegates this task to LAPACK, where the fastest kind of norm to compute is the 1-norm.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that, in the R [help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/norm.html), it makes an explicit reference to DLANGE from LAPACK library which does not compute the 2-norm.

Comment: that is correct, and I have checked the implementation of dlange. But this is a choice made in R, i.e. what the default used norm is.